# Adding more table columns to a list box display query

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have a helper class holding the following code:

```
public static DataSet selectStudent()
{
    MySqlConnection conn = connection();
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM student", conn);
    MySqlCommandBuilder sqlCmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adap);
    DataSet sqlSet = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill (sqlSet, "studentInfo");
    conn.Close();
    return sqlSet;
}
```

And in my form, I have a button to display the student data, this is the code:

```
private void btnStudentView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = studentHelperClass.selectStudent();
    lsbBoxStudent.DataSource = ds.Tables["studentInfo"];
    lsbBoxStudent.DisplayMember = "studentNumber";
}
```

This however, only displays the `studentNumber` row of the table, I need it to display these also `majorField` and `gradePointAverage`.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: is there any reason you can't use data grid view or list view?

Comment: How would I get it to work with the DataGrid? but keep in mind it has to be a button click that uses a method in another class.

Comment: add datagrid to your form and then `yourgrid.DataSource = ds.Tables["studentInfo"];` will do it in your click event

Comment: I'm sorry Im not too familiar with this, do you mind submitting an answer and showing it with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add DataGridView  to your form and name it as `DataGridView1`, then

```
private void btnStudentView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = studentHelperClass.selectStudent();
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["studentInfo"];

}
```

Comment: I managed to figure it out as you posted this, but good thing you did, here are right answer for you. Thanks a lot.